# Slice jquery to default value

Tags: javascript

```
if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
         $(".projects").slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");
     } else if ($(window).width() > 480){
         $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
     };
```

How i can reset from slice 0,8 to default when windows greater than 480? Because when resized the slice 0,8 rule still active? I want to default if greater than 480 how can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use classes. It's much more flexible than `.css`. You need to remove previous class/styles before you slice and assign new:

```
if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
    $projects.removeClass('md').slice(0, 8).addClass('sm');
} else if ($(window).width() > 480) {
    $projects.removeClass('sm').slice(3, 6).addClass('md');
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/96Rxg/

Also consider caching `$('.projects')`, you don't want to select it on each of resize event fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $projects = $(".projects");    
if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
     $projects.slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");
 } else if ($(window).width() > 480){
     $projects.slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
 };
```

Comment: I try to copy paste i not know but something wrong?